# Is there a build-in function to insert escape characters in Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, escaping

Is there a built-in function that automatically escapes characters in a Kotlin string? For instance, given the following input:
`""""name": "apple""""` the output should be `"""\"name\": \"apple\""""`

Edit: need to do it at runtime. I need escape characters in my actual string.

Comment: Do you mean at runtime or in the IDE? It is already done automatically in the IDE. And at runtime there are no escape characters in the actual strings. Escape characters are only for the syntax to be interpreted by the compiler.

Comment: @Tenfour04 at runtime